# Retrofit cannot connect to my local web server on port 3000

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

My app that is using Retrofit (v1.6.1) to connect to REST web services cannot connect to my local web server (running on `localhost`), this is the error I am getting.

This is inside Nexus4 (v4.3) emulator, I am using Android Studio for development and I have added `android.permission.INTERNET` & `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions in manifest file.

The error says its waited for 15s but it does not, it errors out right away.

```
07-13 15:57:53.947      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP POST http://localhost:3000/app/auth/signin
07-13 15:57:54.132      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
07-13 15:57:54.132      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 44
07-13 15:57:54.157      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ {"auth":{"email":"steve","password":"pass"}}
07-13 15:57:54.387      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (44-byte body)
07-13 15:57:54.657      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://localhost:3000/app/auth/signin
07-13 15:57:54.857      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 3000) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:68)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:37)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:68)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:37)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-13 15:57:54.857      820-840/it.test.android.app.activity D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

Comment: **See this link, i gave answer here**: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623872/failed-to-connect-to-localhost-127-0-0-1-android/45127553#45127553)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I solved the issue, need to use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` to connect to my local server.

Found it here - http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: Note that the answer from @Mariusz_Jamro answers exactly that, and came earlier than yours. That should had been the right answer.

Comment: i agree with @XAnguera in the sense that Mariusz_Jamro's answer gets into describing how port 3000 doesn't really have anything to do with his issue. however he could have been more explicit and stating that his phone and the pc have two different ip addresses on the same subnet (router).

Comment: Any idea how to handle this exception? I dont want my app to crash when the local server is not running

Answer (score 63):

On your phone connecting to `localhost:3000` means "connect to port 3000 on local network interface" - which is local interface of the phone, not the port 3000 of the PC to which your phone is connected. There is nothing listening on port 3000 on the phone, so you get connection refused error.

Whould you're trying to do is (probably, hard to guess without more information) is to connect from the phone to port 3000 on you PC. So you should change the address you're connecting to from `localhost` to address of the PC. In case of emulator that would be **10.0.2.2** (which is localhost of the PC). [See networking information](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) for reference.

Comment: I got `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:3334` trying to connect to `localhost:3334` from my emulator to a webserver running my PC

Comment: Wow - I was stuck on this for 2 days.  Thanks for rescuing me from the debugging hole I went down.