# Obtain Array of Objects with retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I've a server running in my localhost with some information in the database that i want to show in my Android application, I'm using the retrofit library to do it but I only get this message:

> error loading from API

Here's my RetrofitClient:

public class RetrofitClient {

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Here is the class with my GET method:

```
public interface SOService {

    @GET("stocks/")
Call<List<Stock>> getStocks();

}
```

Here's my class with the url and how to connect:

```
public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

    public static SOService getSOService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SOService.class);
    }
}
```

And here's where I finally try to obtain the information:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button registerButton;
    private SOService mService;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mService = ApiUtils.getSOService();

        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> loadAnswers());
    }

    public void loadAnswers() {

        System.out.println("Entro aquí");
        mService.getStocks().enqueue(new Callback<List<Stock>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Stock>> call, Response<List<Stock>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                System.out.println("Te lo imprimo");
                System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();
                // handle request errors depending on status code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Stock>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

        }
    });
    }
}
```

I've the class Stock like this:

```
public class Stock {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("ticker")
    @Expose
    private String ticker;
    @SerializedName("open")
    @Expose
    private Double open;
    @SerializedName("close")
    @Expose
    private Double close;
    @SerializedName("volume")
    @Expose
    private Integer volume;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTicker() {
        return ticker;
    }

    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    public Double getOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public void setOpen(Double open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

    public Double getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public void setClose(Double close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public Integer getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(Integer volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

}
```

Any idea why it dosn't work?

Here's the error that I get:

> W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
>   /127.0.0.1:8000
>                     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:242)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>                     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect
>   to /127.0.0.1 (port 8000) from /127.0.0.1 (port 42532) after 10000ms:
>   isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
>                     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:273)
>                     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188)
>                     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
>                     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
>                     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
>                     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>                     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>                     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
>   W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:71)
>                     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
>                     ... 21 more
>                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:262)
>                     ... 31 more

Comment: do you get the same message when you paste that url in your browser?

Comment: you could printstacktrace in t to find out what's the problem

Comment: error posted on the post above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try retrieving a List of objects like this:

```
public interface SOService {

    @GET("stocks/")
    Call<List<Stock>> getStocks();

}

mService.getStocks().enqueue(new Callback<List<Stock>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Stock>> call, Response<List<Stock>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    System.out.println("Te lo imprimo");
                    System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
                }else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    // handle request errors depending on status code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Stock>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

You're trying to connect to a local sever on your computer, but through the emulator. The emulator can't connect to this server. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726670/retrofit-cannot-connect-to-my-local-web-server-on-port-3000). The local URL you're using is going to be used by retrofit to identify a port and address locally on your PHONE (emulator). that's why you can't connect. There's no server on your phone in that address. You need to enter your pc ip address for that to work :)

Comment: Thanks, I edited it, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Try adding t.printStackTrace(); in the onFailure method to see what's going wrong. Or just add a breakpoint and inspect "t"

Comment: Error posted, I think I've a problem with the server

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad i could help :)